# rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks Ubuntu 16.10 server hanging after sometime on

Tags: server

I am trying to setup an Ubuntu Server 16.10. I have installed and updated the system using apt-get. But after sometime running the system hangs and I receive the following error:

[image]

I had a similar issue while running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

I think it may be a hardware problem. But I am looking for a way to determine the cause. Can somebody provide me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

We were having a similar case of the machine freezing within between 10minutes to 6 hours of running time. We were using Linux Mint 18.2 and Ubuntu 16.04 on two different brand new machines with AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processors.

This appeared to be independent of processor load. It could not be causes by stress. It could occur at low core temperature. 
Note that our `syslog` showed the virtually identical error message repeating in 3min intervals.

```
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705896] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705909]  7-...: (3 GPs behind) idle=5df/1/0 softirq=362596/362596 fqs=5806 
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705913]  (detected by 4, t=15002 jiffies, g=556997, c=556996, q=1370)
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705919] Task dump for CPU 7:
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705921] swapper/7       R  running task        0     0      1 0x00000008
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705928]  0000000000000010 0000000000000246 ffff8be1cd6d3e70 0000000000000018
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705933]  7735940000000000 000013745a87802e 0000000000000007 ffff8be1cd6d4000
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705937]  ffff8be1ccffd600 ffffffff826bc300 ffff8be1cd6d0000 ffff8be1cd6d3eb8
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705942] Call Trace:
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705954]  [<ffffffff81f19527>] ? cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705959]  [<ffffffff818c7a0a>] ? call_cpuidle+0x2a/0x50
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705963]  [<ffffffff818c7dee>] ? cpu_startup_entry+0x29e/0x350
Oct 19 14:00:41 blanked_out_usr-desktop kernel: [21450.705967]  [<ffffffff818518b1>] ? start_secondary+0x151/0x190
```

After we started using the proprietary AMD processor microcode firmware (amd64-microcode / Version 2.20160316.1), both machines were running at first without apparent stalling. Yet, only after kernel update (to 4.10 on the Mint machine and 4.13 on the Ubuntu machine), the machines did not exhibit stalling anymore. This was evaluated over a period of ~48h.